# Wait till file gets copy/upload completes

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, nfs

I have to wait till file copy/upload finishes completely  using python (preferred approach), bash/shell also fine(I will call from python)

I have shared nfs directory /data/files_in/, if somebody copies/uploads a file to /data/files_in/ directory, I should notify to other application, only after complete file copy/upload is done

My current code to check file is completed copied or not

```
            while True:

                current_size =  Path(file_path).stat().st_size
                time.sleep(5)
                result_size = Path(file_path).stat().st_size

                if result_size == current_size:
                    break
            # Notify your application
```

It is working only with small size files, for large files like 100G files it is not working properly.

I have increased a timer, but still sometimes it is failing and timer based approach seems not good idea to rely on.

Is there any other way, I can implement code to fix this issue?

OS: Linux, Cent os
Python Version: 3.9

Comment: _it is not working properly_  : What does this mean?

Comment: Meaning before file copying it is coming out from while loop

Comment: You never check whether copying is finished. You only check if the file size hasn't changed during the last 5 seconds.

Comment: yes, Currently I am using file size as logic, to check complete or not, if no change, file copied completed.

Comment: I don't think there is a foolproof way to find out, whether copying is completed, unlesss you communicate somehow with the process itself which creates that file. So, every heuristic you think off, may break occasionally.

Comment: Yes, Might be true.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will ask here. Shouldn't the resulting size be larger (or at least different) from the current one in order for a file to be done uploading and therefore stop the loop?

Comment: I am assuming, if current and result size not changed, its done  because I am checking same file path

Answer (score 0):

I assume you cannot establish any kind of direct communications with the other process, i.e. the one which is copying/uploading the file.

One common approach in these cases is to have the other process to write/erase a "semaphore" file. It may be that it creates the semaphore just before beginning copying and erases it just after finishing, so the semaphore means "don't do anything, I'm still running", or the other way round, it creates the semaphore just after finishing and erases it just before starting next time, so the semaphore means "your data are ready to use".

That said, I'm amazed your approach doesn't work if you allow enough time, and 5 secs should be more than enough on any networks